# User not authorized to perform: iam:PassRole on resource error in creating AWS codepipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline

I am trying to set up a continuous delivery pipeline for Lambda function following this tutorial, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/build-pipeline.html. This is my first time setting it up. Now I am stuck on the step, creating the pipeline and it is giving me the following error when I click on the create pipeline button.

[image]

I exactly followed the steps mentioned in the link. Why am I getting that error?

You can see the preview of my configuration here.

[image]

[image]

What is wrong with my configuration? It is giving me this error as well.

```
Stack [lambda-pipeline-stack] does not exist
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CloudFormation is not authorized to perform: iam:PassRole on resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51911382/cloudformation-is-not-authorized-to-perform-iampassrole-on-resource)

Comment: But it is not mentioning the role in my case as you can see the error message. just say xxxxx:root.

Comment: Give the iam:PassRole permission to your IAM User or Role.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps someone -
The error basically says that

> the lambda has no permission to perform/do `iam:PassRole` on a
> specific resource/service you are trying to use/manipulate with
> lambda.

To solve this on your lamnda policy add this -

```
{
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iam:PassRole"
        ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
```